# Which tag is used to display the data in the tabular form

Tags: html, css

The tag is used to group header content in an HTML table .The element is used in conjunction with the elements to specify each part of the table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tags which is used to create a table in HTML as follows:
table tag
th tag (Heading 1) th
th tag (Heading 2) th
tr tag start
td tagdata 1 td
td data 2 td
tr tag close
table tag close

Note: open and close these tags properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are some tags which is used to create a table in HTML as follows: table tag i.e. th tag (Heading 1) & th th tag (Heading 2) & th tr tag start td tagdata 1 td td data 2 td tr tag close table tag close

Note: Please open and close these tags properly

Hope, this solves your problem.